# Create a common view in all fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i made a drawerlayout , and i have 5-6 framgment, i want to have a some same components in all fragment, like a lower relative ayout with a webview which will be show in all fragment
i write below code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="30dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

now i can show this textview from all fragment, but i can only control in main activity, how can i get it access from all fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an `Interface` for the Fragments to access the View through your Activity if that is where you want to maintain it:

```
public class MyBaseFragment extends Fragment
{
    MyTextViewInterface textViewInterface;

    public Interface TextViewInterface
    {
        public TextView getTextView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            textViewInterface = (MyTextViewInterface) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Parent Activity deosn't implement 'MyTextViewInterface'");
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement MyTextViewInterface");
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyTextViewInterface
{
    TextView textView;
    ...

    @Override
    public TextView getTextView()
    {
        return this.textView;
    }
}
```

Then to get the TextView just call `textViewInterface.getTextView()` from your Fragament.

Note that I've omitted a lot of the required methods for FragmentActivity and Fragment.